# SqlAlchemy "contains_eager" does not appear to load nested relationships

Tags: python, python-2.7, sqlalchemy, eager-loading

I have a schema as follows:

```
Thing # Base class for below tables
- id

Ball (Thing)
- color

Bin (Thing)
- ball -> Ball.id

Court (Thing)
- homeBin -> Bin.id
- awayBin -> Bin.id
```

I'd like to ensure that whenever I load a set of `Court`s, it includes the latest `Ball` column values. From what I understand, [contains_eager()](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/loading_relationships.html#sqlalchemy.orm.contains_eager) might be able to help with that:

> Indicate that the given attribute should be eagerly loaded from columns stated manually in the query.

I have a test that queries every few seconds for any `Court`s. I'm finding that, even with `contains_eager`, I only ever see the same value for `Ball`.color, even though I've explicitly updated the column's value in the database.

Why does sqlalchemy appear to reuse this old data?

Below is a working example of what's happening:

```
from sqlalchemy import *
from sqlalchemy.orm import *
from sqlalchemy.ext.associationproxy import association_proxy
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base

Base = declarative_base()

class Thing(Base):
    __tablename__ = "Things"
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String(256))
    thingType = Column(String(256))
    __mapper_args__ = {
            'with_polymorphic':'*',
            'polymorphic_on':"thingType",
            'polymorphic_identity':"thing"
        }


class Ball(Thing):
    __tablename__ = "Balls"
    id = Column('id', Integer, ForeignKey('Things.id'), primary_key=True)
    color = Column('color', String(256))
    __mapper_args__ = {
        'polymorphic_identity':'ball'
    }

class Bin(Thing):
    __tablename__ = "Bins"
    id = Column('id', Integer, ForeignKey('Things.id'), primary_key=True)
    shape = Column('shape', String(256))
    ballId = Column('ballId', Integer, ForeignKey('Balls.id'))
    ball = relationship(Ball, foreign_keys=[ballId], backref="outputBins")
    __mapper_args__ = {
        'polymorphic_identity':'bin'
    }
    pass

class Court(Thing):
    __tablename__ = "Courts"
    id = Column('id', Integer, ForeignKey('Things.id'), primary_key=True)
    homeBinId = Column('homeBinId', Integer, ForeignKey('Bins.id'))
    awayBinId = Column('awayBinId', Integer, ForeignKey('Bins.id'))
    homeBin = relationship(Bin, foreign_keys=[homeBinId], backref="homeCourts")
    awayBin = relationship(Bin, foreign_keys=[awayBinId], backref="awayCourts")
    __mapper_args__ = {
        'polymorphic_identity':'court'
    }

metadata = MetaData()
engine = create_engine("postgresql://localhost:5432/")
Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
session = Session()

def courtQuery():
    awayBalls = aliased(Ball, name="awayBalls")
    homeBalls = aliased(Ball, name="homeBalls")
    awayBins = aliased(Bin, name="awayBins")
    homeBins = aliased(Bin, name="homeBins")

    query = session.query(Court)\
        .outerjoin(awayBins, Court.awayBinId == awayBins.id)\
        .outerjoin(awayBalls, awayBins.ballId == awayBalls.id)\
        .outerjoin(homeBins, Court.homeBinId == homeBins.id)\
        .outerjoin(homeBalls, homeBins.ballId == homeBalls.id)\
        .options(contains_eager(Court.awayBin, alias=awayBins).contains_eager(awayBins.ball, alias=awayBalls))\
        .options(contains_eager(Court.homeBin, alias=homeBins).contains_eager(homeBins.ball, alias=homeBalls))
    return [r for r in query]

import time

while(True):
    results = courtQuery()
    court = results[0]
    ball = court.homeBin.ball
    print(ball.color) # does not change
    time.sleep(2)
```

Environment:

- Python 2.7.14
- SqlAlchemy 1.3.0b1
- PostGres 11.3 (though I've seen this
  on Oracle as well)

Comment: Looks like an issue with the way you're handling session and transaction lifetime. Usually it's also better to include the [mcve] in the post itself.

Comment: @IljaEverilä - Ah interesting. I had figured the above code was the issue, so it hadn't crossed my mind to consider the session. How might I handle the session differently? I'll also update the code to contain a fuller representation of what's happening.

Comment: I'm not saying it is for certain the case, but often when it seems that updates are not being read it is a case of not committing/rolling back and/or closing a session timely. SQLAlchemy operates under certain assumptions about transaction isolation, so if you've read some object in the session from the DB before, it does not update its state when it sees the same row by id again. The [side note here](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/session_state_management.html#when-to-expire-or-refresh) explains it better than I can, including edge cases and the like.

Comment: It looks like the session may be the culprit. Inserting an "session.expire_all()" before the query is executed does ensure that new data is fetched. I think I'm just uncertain as to how contains_eager works, if it does eagerly fetch the latest data, but does not actually updated the objects.